# Отформатировать код. Где настроить исключения для форматирования?

Tags: visual-studio-code

У меня в HTML документе есть CSS код в элементе Style.
При форматировании он разбивается по строкам, а мне нужно, чтобы CSS код был одной строкой.

Как это сделать? Где настроить исключения для форматирования?
Можно ли настроить исключение для элемента?
Может можно настроить расширение Prettier и ESint?

Comment: В общих настройка ищите. Там же можно настроить и prettier и eslint

Comment: Никто не знает ?

Comment: Я уже написал. Открываете settings и в поиск вбиваете prettier и eslint, настраиваете их.